# Enable the CodeArtifact credential provider for nuget in Rider

Tags: nuget, rider, aws-codeartifact

I've configured my credential provider and it works fine with nuget and dotnet cli.
(instructions used https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/nuget-cli.html#nuget-configure-cli)

I've enabled nuget credential providers in Rider. (under settings -> Build/Execution/Deployment)

I'm using `aws sso login` and have my profile setup correctly (I think? Maybe Rider is different?)

When I try to do a nuget restore I get prompted for a username/password for my CodeArtifact source. How do I get the credential provider working?

Using Rider 2023.2.1 on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

1. In your zsh. Set the NUGET_PLUGIN_PATHS to $HOME/.nuget/plugins/netcore/AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGetCredentialProvider/AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGetCredentialProvider.dll (or relevant path)
2. In the Rider settings --> NuGet --> Credential Providers. Set the "Use credentials provider" to "NuGet/.NET CLI plugins"
3. In the Rider settings --> NuGet --> Restore. Set the "PackageReferenece Restore Engine" to "Console"

Hope this helps.